# Running a bat file with BCP command, getting connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I have a bat file that is using the `bcp` command to execute a stored procedure to a delimited file. When manually running the bat file, I get the following errors:

[image]

I'm using the `-T` parameter as I log into the database with Windows Authentication.  Is there a setting I may need to change to fix this error?

Comment: Just to confirm - the SQL Server is running on `localhost`, yes?

Comment: Yes, it is. The bat file and the SQL Server are located on the same machine.

Comment: And you can connect to the SQL Server using `SQLCMD`, or `BCP` outside of the batch file?

Comment: RB - looks like I needed to add the -S argument to the command specifying the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-S [DATABASE HOST NAME]` argument needed to be passed to the `bcp` command.